# "Embedding" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico

I always have difficulties to translate the English word **`embedding`** to Spanish.

I see that RAE has the word:

> **[Embeber](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=Q2UrxqADmDXX2EwDzunc)**
>
> 1. tr. Dicho de un cuerpo sólido: Absorber a otro líquido. La esponja embebe el agua.
> 2. tr. Empapar, llenar de un líquido algo poroso o esponjoso. Embebieron una esponja en vinagre.
> 3. tr. Dicho de una cosa: Contener, encerrar dentro de sí a otra.
> 4. tr. Dicho de una cosa inmaterial: Incorporar, incluir dentro de sí a otra.

But also **`encajar`** could match in case of [the Mathematical concept](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encaje_(matem%C3%A1tica)).

Is there any standard translation for this word?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that in computer science, the Spanish language is using *embebido* (embeber) as an anglicism.

For [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_embebido)

> Un sistema **embebido** (anglicismo de embedded) o **empotrado** (**integrado**, **incrustado**) es un sistema de computación diseñado para realizar una o algunas pocas funciones dedicadas,1 2 frecuentemente en un sistema de computación en tiempo real.

So it seems that *embebido, empotrado, integrado or incrustado* could be used for *embedded*, but the standard translation (in computer science) is `embebido`.

Since you point to a different accepted translation for maths, (`encajar` vs. `embeber`) it seems that there is no standard or single translation for this word across different domains (maths, computer science, etc.).

Comment: Just to support this answer of you vs your other one, here is a link to Fundéu, acknowledging embeber's use for abstract things such as code: http://www.fundeu.es/escribireninternet/entendiendo-a-los-disenadores-las-claves-de-su-vocabulario/ Edit: but, of course, we lack @fedorqui's context, if he wants to physically embed a thing into another, I would *maybe* use incrustar instead.

Comment: Reading my previous comment, I think that the answer to fedorqui's real question is "no, there isn't".

Comment: @guillem You are right, I didn't phrase the question very well : ) Now as well as we know there is no one to one relationship among words in English and Spanish for this case, it is good to have this set of suggestions Diego provided.

Answer (score 2):

Como han dicho recientemente, embebido se usa, aunque a los hispano-hablantes, nos suena una palabra forzada.

Lo que si usamos mucho es el término `integrado`, que significaría como los engranajes se integran para formar una maquinaria perfecta.

> El sistema está integrado por una arquitectura compleja, compuesta por...