# ¿Cómo traducir "embed" en el contexto de software?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico, informática

Acabo de ver una pregunta en Stack Overflow en español que para mí suena horrible: [Trato de **embeber** XML en docxtemplater, pero no funciona](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/195924/83).

> [image]

Sin duda **embeber** quiere ser la traducción de **embed**. Para traducir **to embed** utilizaría en este caso **incrustar**. Mi pregunta: ¿Hay una mejor traducción para **embed**?

Comment: @ukemi great edit! Thanks for making questions better. Bienvenido/a al sitio enxaneta.

Comment: I would say it is a duplicate of [“Embedding” in Spanish?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/13471/1674)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es un uso aceptado de *embeber*:

> [«"embebido": participio de embeber, en la 5ª acepción: encajar, embutir o meter algo dentro de otra cosa.»](http://dle.rae.es/embeber)
>
> - *Diccionario de la lengua española* (23.ª edición)

Y además, el más común que he visto en este contexto.

Dicho eso, hay multiples opciones para traducir la frase "embedded [software/systems]":

- embebido<sup>1</sup>
- empotrado<sup>1</sup>
- insertado<sup>1</sup>

---

1. [*El software y los sistemas embebidos*](https://web.archive.org/web/20100705072033/http://swiki.lifia.info.unlp.edu.ar/prospectiva/uploads/2/El_software_y_los_sistemas_embebidos_-Andres_Dmitruk.doc), Universidad de la Plata.

Comment: Creo que en España se utilizar con más frequencia: empotrado,software o sistema empotrado